# Составить запрос к БД c помощью конструкторов запроса Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Как составать такой запрос с помощью конструкторов запроса Laravel?

```
$flights = DB::select('SELECT `id`,`title`,`pic` FROM `articles`
ORDER BY `articles`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1,2');
```

И возможно ли применить конструкторы по отношению к моделям?

Comment: `$flights = DB::table('articles')->select('id', 'title', 'pic')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->skip(2)->take(1)->get();`, ну или же вместо `DB::table('articles')` - `Article::select(...) и т.д.`..

Comment: Работает, только пропустить один, взять 2 `->skip(1)->take(2)`

Comment: Ну `LIMIT 1, 2` равно `LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2`, при этом `skip` используется для `offset`, а `take` для `limit`, поэтому да :)